# Are there any up-to-date works reporting how efficient word prediction and spelling correction systems are in terms of user experience?

Tags: usability-study, autocomplete, auto-correct

I'm looking for both methods for measuring efficiency of such systems, and any empirical studies which I can use as an evidence to convince investors. For example:

- 25% of Android users use word prediction module every day.
- Only 10% of spell correction suggestions of Android is accepted by users.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read this paper through properly but it (or some of the references it cites) looks like it will contain the information you are looking for: [The length of text messages and use of predictive text: Who uses it and how much do they have to say?](http://auislandora.wrlc.org/islandora/object/tesolworkingpapers%3A3/datastream/PDF/view)